# Django - forms trying to clean unique together, CrispyError

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model with a unique together and I want to validate this condition in my modelform.  The unique together includes a field that is passed to the form in an **init** method, the user, and a field that is in the form. I'm having problems with validating a unique together condition.

**EDIT**
I have modified the code to what you see below

model:

```
class Objective(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objective_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    mode = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='LA')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'objective_name', 'course']
        ordering = ['objective_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.objective_name
```

The view:

```
def addobjective(request, course_id):
    this_course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=course_id)
    user = request.user
    all_courses = Course.objects.filter(user=user)
    objective_list = Objective.objects.filter(
        course=this_course).order_by('objective_name')
    context = {'objective_list': objective_list}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ObjectiveForm(user, request.POST, my_course=this_course)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.course = this_course
            obj.user = user
            obj.save()
            form = ObjectiveForm(user, my_course=this_course)
            context['form'] = form

            return redirect('gradebook:addobjective', course_id=this_course.id)
    else:
        form = ObjectiveForm(user, my_course=this_course)
        context['form'] = form

    context['this_course'] = this_course
    context['all_courses'] = all_courses

    return render(request, 'gradebook/objective-form.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
class ObjectiveForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        my_course = kwargs.pop('my_course')
        self.objs = Objective.objects.filter(user=user, course=my_course)
        super(ObjectiveForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Objective
        fields = ('objective_name', 'description', 'mode',)

    def clean(self):
        super(ObjectiveForm, self).clean()
        objective_name = self.cleaned_data.get("objective_name")
        description = self.cleaned_data.get("description")
        mode = self.cleaned_data.get("mode")

        if self.objs.filter(objective_name=objective_name).count() > 0:
            print("error")
            del self.cleaned_data["objective_name"]
            del self.cleaned_data["description"]
            del self.cleaned_data["mode"]
            raise ValidationError(
                "This course already has a learning objective with this name.")

        return self.cleaned_data
```

**EDIT**

The error I know get is `|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field`.  This occurs when I enter in a value for `objective_name` that is a duplicate.  `error` is printed to the console and then I get the above error. I do not get the ValidationError.
[The full traceback can be seen here.](https://gist.github.com/shmish/40ab48dfa9069a1769689deea5e21e9d)

**Maybe with the form I do not need the unique together constraint in the model?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was caused by improper indentation of `return redirect('gradebook:addobjective', course_id=this_course.id)` after the `if form.is_valid():`.  The return redirect has to be a part of the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my_course field is not defined in Objective model , so maybe you need to change this line:

form = ObjectiveForm(request.POST, my_course=this_course)

To

form = ObjectiveForm(request.POST, course=this_course)